# How to access function from class into another php file

Tags: php

I'm trying to access my function from class using if condition where my function that contains SQL Statement what I want to do is access it from another php file using if condition if it's existing it will return true. Codes below.

**main.html**

```js
< script type = "text/javascript"
src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" >
  < /script>
 
 <script>
    
 $(document).on("click", "#addBooksId", function() 
 {
      $.get("addBooks.html", function(data) 
   { 
          $( "#myform" ).empty();
          $('#myform').append(data); / / Receive with value
alert('This is add books section');
});
});





< /script>
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}
#container {
  background-color: #707070;
}
#menu {
  width: 1250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}
#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  /*Remove bullets*/
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#menu ul li:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
#menu ul li a,
visited {
  color: #CCC;
  /*Color of text*/
  display: block;
  /*Takes up the full width available*/
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #CCC;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
#menu ul ul li {
  display: block;
}
#menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #707070;
  min-width: 140px;
  /*Width when hover*/
}
#menu ul ul li a:hover
/*Color of text when hover*/

{
  color: #099;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="menu">
    <ul>



      <li>

        <a href="#">Manage Books</a>

        <ul>
          <div id="addBooksId">
            <li><a href="#">Add Books</a>
            </li>
          </div>
        </ul>

      </li>





    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="myform">

  <p></p>
</div>
```

This is my home page where the user can choose an option. After clicking the option in drop down menu. It will redirect me to the `addBooks.html` where the user will fill up the following textfield.

**addBooks.html**

```css
<style type="text/css"> .addBooks {
  clear: both;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
.addBooks label {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: right;
}
.addBooks input {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.addBooks select {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="addBooks">
    <h1>Add Books</h1>
    <hr>

    <form method="post" action="../process/bookProcess.php">

      <fieldset>

        <div class="form-field">
          <label for="name">Book Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="bookName" required>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div class="form-field">
          <label for="edition">Edition:</label>
          <input type="text" id="edition" name="bookEdition" required>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div class="form-field">
          <label for="pages">Pages:</label>
          <input type="text" id="pages" name="bookPages" required>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div class="form-field">
          <label for="language">Language:</label>
          <input type="text" id="language" name="bookLanguage" required>
        </div>


        <div class="form-field">
          <input type="submit" id="submitBooks" value="Submit">
        </div>
      </fieldset>

    </form>

  </div>
  <!--- end of addBooks --->

</div>
<!--- end of container --->
```

**connection.php**

```
<?php
//PHP CONSTANTS
DEFINE ('host', 'localhost'); 
DEFINE ('username', 'root');
DEFINE ('password', '');
DEFINE ('database', 'librarysystem');

function getConnection()
{
$myDB = mysqli_connect(host,username,password,database);

if (!$myDB)
{
    trigger_error ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else
{
    return $myDB;
}
}

?>
```

I created a connection so I will just call it from every file that I want to use. Here in my `booksCRUD.php` I created a protected string so I can access it anywhere. I already use this method in my login. So this is the second time I'll use this in my INSERT statement.

**bookCRUD.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class booksCRUD{

    private $accessMyDB;

    public function __construct(){
       $this->accessMyDB = getConnection();
    } 

    public function createBook($dbBookName,$dbEdition,$dbPages,$dbLanguage){
        $statement = $this->accessMyDB->prepare("INSERT INTO bookmodule (bookName, bookEdition, bookPages, bookLanguage) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $statement->bind_param("ssss", $dbBookName,$dbEdition,$dbPages,$dbLanguage);

        if($statement->execute()){
            $statement->close();
            return true;
        }else{
            echo "Failed: " . $this->accessMyDB->error;
            return false;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

**bookProcess.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once('../connection/connection.php');
require_once('../crud/bookCRUD.php');

if(isset($_POST['submitBooks'])){
    $dbBookName = $_POST['bookName'];
    $dbEdition = $_POST['bookEdition'];
    $dbPages = $_POST['bookPages'];
    $dbLanguage = $_POST['bookLanguage'];

    if(!empty($dbBookName) && !empty($dbEdition) && !empty($dbPages) && !empty($dbLanguage)){
        $obj = new booksCRUD();
        if(method_exists($obj,'createBook')){
           if($obj->createBook($dbBookName,$dbEdition,$dbPages,$dbLanguage)){
                echo "Successful!";
            }else{
                echo "error";
            }
        }else{
            // method doesn't exist
        }
    }else{
        echo "all fields are required";
    }
}
?>
```

I created a object in my if condition but I cannot access my function correct me if I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: make a object and call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`method_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) function to check if a method exists or not, and then call the method, like this:

```
if(method_exists(new booksCRUD,'createBook')){
    // method exists
}else{
    // method doesn't exist
}
```

## Update:

There are several errors in your code, such as:

- See this statement,

  ```
  $dbLanguange = $_POST['bookLanguage'];
           ^ it should be $dbLanguage
  ```
- See the condition of your `if` clause,

  ```
  if(!empty($dbBookName) && !empty($dbEdition) && !empty($dbPages) && empty($dbLanguage))
                                                                      ^ it should be !empty($dbLanguage)
  ```
- Since you're not planning to access `$accessMyDB` property outside of the class `booksCRUD`, it's better that you make it `private`.
- See this line,

  ```
  echo "Error" . $mysqli->error();
  ```

Your connection handler `$mysqli` is not available in this scope.

So **the solution** would be, keep your **connection.php** as it is and change your **bookCRUD.php** and **bookProcess.php** in the following way:

**bookCRUD.php:**

```
<?php

    class booksCRUD{

        private $accessMyDB;

        public function __construct(){
           $this->accessMyDB = getConnection();
        } 

        public function createBook($dbBookName,$dbEdition,$dbPages,$dbLanguage){
            $statement = $this->accessMyDB->prepare("INSERT INTO bookmodule (bookName, bookEdition, bookPages, bookLanguage) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $statement->bind_param("ssss", $dbBookName,$dbEdition,$dbPages,$dbLanguage);

            if($statement->execute()){
                $statement->close();
                return true;
            }else{
                echo "Failed: " . $this->accessMyDB->error;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

**bookProcess.php:**

```
<?php

    session_start();
    require_once('../connection/connection.php');
    require_once('../crud/booksCRUD.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submitBooks'])){
        $dbBookName = $_POST['bookName'];
        $dbEdition = $_POST['bookEdition'];
        $dbPages = $_POST['bookPages'];
        $dbLanguage = $_POST['bookLanguage'];

        if(!empty($dbBookName) && !empty($dbEdition) && !empty($dbPages) && !empty($dbLanguage)){
            $obj = new booksCRUD();
            if(method_exists($obj,'createBook')){
               if($obj->createBook($dbBookName,$dbEdition,$dbPages,$dbLanguage)){
                    echo "Successful!";
                }else{
                    echo "error";
                }
            }else{
                // method doesn't exist
            }
        }else{
            echo "all fields are required";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Hi! I follow your code but it didn't work for me. I updated my post please see. :)

Comment: @JohnFrancis Have you included *connection.php* in *bookCRUD.php* page? I don't see any `require_once('connection.php');` there.

Comment: I didn't put `require_once('connection.php');` in my script. I just access it directly in my constructor. From what I read I don't need to create a instance of an object so I just directly access it. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: @JohnFrancis What issue you're facing now? All I can see is, you're not calling `createBook()` method after checking it's existence.

Comment: I call `createBook()` under if statement `method_exists` It doesn't print any error to me. Please see my updated post.

Comment: `@JohnFrancis I've updated my answer. Please see the **update** section of my answer.

Comment: @JohnFrancis Also I feel that this line `require_once('../crud/booksCRUD.php');` is fishy. You named the page as  *bookCRUD.php* but you're including *booksCRUD.php*, so fix this.

Comment: Appreciated your help and tips but bro it still printing no sign in my `bookProcess.php` and it still didn't insert into database. Please see my update post for the last time.

Comment: @JohnFrancis 1) You didn't change *bookCRUD.php* and *bookProcess.php* page as per my **Update** section, did you? 2) Look at [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247365/how-to-access-function-from-class-into-another-php-file/37247452?noredirect=1#comment62025284_37247452) above. 3) You're missing `name` attribute in your input submit element, it should be like this: `<input type="submit" name="submitBooks" id="submitBooks" value="Submit">` 4) Your JavaScript and CSS is not relevant here.

Comment: Finally its working! I didn't notice that I didn't put name "submitBooks". Really appreciated your help and time bro. You're the best.

Comment: @JohnFrancis Glad I could help. *Cheers!* :-)

Comment: This is the second time you answered my question. So glad your always ready to help :)

Answer (score 0):

in your bookProcess.php

```
 if(!empty($dbBookName) && !empty($dbEdition) && !empty($dbPages) && empty($dbLanguage)) // If not empty
        {
$obj=new booksCRUD;//create object
$res=$obj->createBook($dbBookName,$dbEdition,$dbPages,$dbLanguage);//call FUNCTION HERE       

if($res==true){
echo "Successful!";
}
else{
echo "Error";
}
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error POST Values are empty";
        }
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me. Please see my updated post.